# how to multy colemn index in postgres 14

Tags: postgresql

i don't really understand PostgreSQL composite indexes

well the scenario is simple

simple table

```sql
create table x(
  id int generated always as identity primary key,
  f1 int not null,
  f2 int not null,
  d date not null,
  constraint "U_constraint_name" unique(f1,f2,d)
);
```

when i select data

```sql
-- ...
where f1= 1 and f2 = 2 and d = '2022-5-18';
```

the unique index don't get fired
why?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: My guess is that the table is too small for an index scan to be efficient.

Comment: with a DO block i inserted random data
it's giving me filter and seq scan